# Detect if url is that of the Pages Module

Tags: module, pages, page-uri

Is there a way to know if the current url being called is that of the Pages Module?

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
{if pages_module =="TRUE"}
     This is a page generated from the pages module!
{else:if}
     This is not a page
{/if}
```

I looked for an add-on though, maybe I'm missing it or maybe I'm missing a simple tag in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {if page_uri} {!-- or {if pages_url} --}
         This is a page in the pages module
    {if:else}
         This is not
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```